# Facebook app approval process for Android and later on iOS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, vuforia

I am creating a FB app & using taggable_friends API. I have 2 issues, for which I need help with:

1. I currently have the Android version developed, so when I submit the FB for approval, I am choosing the platform as Android. In 2-3 weeks I would have the iOS version ready. How do I resubmit it for approval, without it disturbing the Android version?
2. I am building the app using Vuforia. They dont allow for a simulator build. So how do I submit this with FB for an approval?

Any help with this would be appreciated.